Could we have resizable profile pictures?
A lot of times, when I want to choose a new profile picture, I have to go through multiple because they show up as either too small or too big.
It would be great if we have some kind of square box we can drag around and resize, and everything inside that box only is the profile picture.

Yes, that would be nice (I know some other websites with profiles have that feature), but there are plenty of other feature requests that add real/more value to the Stack Exchange network. And developers can only work on a limited number of them.
It should not be too hard to find an application on your device that enables you to create a 256 by 256 pixel image, and those probably allow more editing options like filters and annotations if you need them. (Because that's likely what people will going to be asking for next.)

"there are plenty of other feature requests that add real/more value to the Stack Exchange network" - not to mention, these sites aren't social media.
